# How to wire a ceiling light with 2 wires to ceiling with 3 wires?

Tags: wiring

Our ceiling has three wires...one white, one black, and one green.  The new light fixture we bought only has a white and one black wire.  What should I do with the green wire in the ceiling?

Answer (score 3):

The green is the ground wire.  If the work box is metal then the box itself should have a grounding screw and you should connect the green to that.  Otherwise you don't need to do anything with the green wire.

Comment: I would also recommend testing the wire to make sure that it's *really* grounded, before connecting it to the box.

Answer (score 1):

Some fixtures dont have a ground wire - but do have a ground screw where you are supposed to connect to.  The installation manual should tell you if that is the case.